# calculation in case_when giving odd error

Tags: r

Trying make an agile interest rate calculator on a number of loans of different types. Specifically, this calculation trying to determine the compounding periods based upon the date of the loan and type of compounding ... monthly, quarterly or annually.

dput data for "notes" df:

```
structure(list(`TX Date` = structure(c(1629849600, 1629331200, 
1629158400, 1628208000, 1600041600, 1462492800, 1329436800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Interest Type` = c("Simple", "Simple", "Simple", 
"Compounding", "Simple", "Simple", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -7L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code that has the issue:

```
notes <- notes %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(as.numeric(TTLperiods)=case_when(
    `Interest Type`=="Simple"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="year")),
    `Interest Type`=="Compounding"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month")),
    `Interest Type`=="Quarterly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="quarter")),
    `Interest Type`=="Monthly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month"))-1),
    TRUE~length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by='year'))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
  `Interest Type`=="Simple"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="year")),
Error: unexpected ',' in "  `Interest Type`=="Simple"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="year")),"
>   `Interest Type`=="Compounding"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month")),
Error: unexpected ',' in "  `Interest Type`=="Compounding"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month")),"
>   `Interest Type`=="Quarterly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="quarter")),
Error: unexpected ',' in "  `Interest Type`=="Quarterly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="quarter")),"
>   `Interest Type`=="Monthly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month"))-1),
Error: unexpected ')' in "  `Interest Type`=="Monthly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month"))-1)"
>   TRUE~length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by='year'))) %>% ungroup()
Error: unexpected ')' in "  TRUE~length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by='year')))"
>
```

Have counted the ',' and the ")" and they all seem consistent yet this calc does not work.

Comment: You're trying to assign a vector to `as.numeric(TTLperiods)`. I'm not sure what you want to convert to numeric, but you should probably just be assigning to `TTLperiods`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Was related to a similar problem others have seen with data types.  There was an NA value in the data and since all the RHS calculations are processed first, that NA caused all the data to be considered "logical" type when I really needed 'integer' type.  using "NA_integer_" screen to catch the NA and turn the result into an integer and emphasizing the #L for the other data seems to have fixed this.  The working code below:

```
notes <- notes %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(TTLperiods=case_when(
  is.na(`Interest Type`)~NA_integer_,
  `Interest Type`=="Simple"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="year"))-1L,
 `Interest Type`=="Compounding"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month"))-1L,
  `Interest Type`=="Quarterly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="quarter"))-1L,
  `Interest Type`=="Monthly"~ length(seq(as.Date(`TX Date`), today(), by="month"))-1L)) %>%
   ungroup()
```